# How to embed spreadsheet in HTML form and store values in DB?

Tags: php, excel, mysqli, spreadsheet

I am developing a quiz system where i need to embed spreadsheet as an input field where users will solve equations and submit their answer which will be stored in the MySQL db.

I have searched around but couldn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Show us what you have got so far, what isn't working as expected (code), so we can help you on your way.

Comment: So far I have used TinyMCE for descriptive answers, radios for MCQs, checkboxes for MRQs but now stuck at spreadsheet. no clue for that.. I have downloaded the trail version of SpreadJs. now studying it.